# utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8d

Tags: python, utf-8, passwords, wifi

Since I'm new to python, I watched a tutorial on the internet. I understood the code and wanted to run it on my own computer. But I encountered this error.

```
import subprocess

import re

command_output = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()

profile_names = (re.findall("All User Profile     : (.*)\r", command_output))

wifi_list = []

if len(profile_names) != 0:
    for name in profile_names:
        
        wifi_profile = {}
        
        profile_info = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
        
        if re.search("Security key           : Absent", profile_info):
            continue
        else:
            
            wifi_profile["ssid"] = name
            
            profile_info_pass = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name, "key=clear"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
            
            password = re.search("Key Content            : (.*)\r", profile_info_pass)
            
            if password == None:
                wifi_profile["password"] = None
            else:
                
                wifi_profile["password"] = password[1]
            
            wifi_list.append(wifi_profile) 

for x in range(len(wifi_list)):
    print(wifi_list[x])
```

Giving error like that. Although I understand the error a little. I don't know how to do that. Like I said, I'm fairly new to python and programming.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\wifi_passwords.py", line 27, in <module>
    command_output = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 599: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Add more info into post. Add output from `subprocess.run` before decoding

Comment: [`set "PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8:backslashreplace"`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonioencoding#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING)?